# Is there any way to add the field in document but hide it from _source, also document should be analysed and searchable

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-mapping

I want to add one field to the document which should be searchable but when we do get/search it should not appear under _source.

I have tried index and store options but its not achievable through it.
Its more like _all or copy_to, but in my case value is provided by me (not collecting from other fields of the document.)

I am looking for mapping through which I can achieve below cases.

When I put document :

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "title":   "Some short title",
  "date":    "2015-01-01",
  "content": "A very long content field..."
}
```

and do search

GET my_index/_search

output should be

```
{
    "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Some short title",
          "date" : "2015-01-01"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

also when I do the below search

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "content",
      "query": "long content"
    }
  }
}
```

it should result me

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.5753642,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.5753642,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Some short title",
          "date" : "2015-01-01"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: What is your mapping?  When you say "I have tried index and store options but its not achievable through it", what combination have you tried and what results do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this using below mapping :

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {

    "_doc": {
      "_source": {
        "excludes": [
          "content"
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "store": true 
        },
        "date": {
          "type": "date",
          "store": true 
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Add document :

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "title":   "Some short title",
  "date":    "2015-01-01",
  "content": "A very long content field..."
}
```

When you run the query to search content on the field 'content' :

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "content",
      "query": "long content"
    }
  }
}
```

You will get the result with hits as below:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.5753642,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.5753642,
        "_source" : {
          "date" : "2015-01-01",
          "title" : "Some short title"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

It hides the field 'content'. :)

Hence achieved it with the help of mapping. You don't need to exclude it from query each time you make get/search call.

More read on source : 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/mapping-source-field.html

Comment: Great use of [mapping-level source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/mapping-source-field.html#include-exclude)! Nice job!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) to exclude the `content` field:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "_source": {
    "excludes": [ "content" ]
  },
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "content",
      "query": "long content"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for something at mapping level which will hide the 'content' field on search.

Comment: I want something like copy_to, in case of copy_to the copied to field is searchable but it is not shown in search.
For reference:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/copy-to.html

Comment: After research come to conclusion that only way to hide the field from search is to exclude. Thanks @Val

Comment: What happened ?

Comment: I have posted the answer. please check.